# An enhanced Marquee tag in javascript. How can I make it smoother?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've read that the `<marquee>` tag is to return in html5... however, I need a solution which will work in IE6... so with that said, I've given myself the brief of re-implementing the Marquee tag, using standards compliant code, and enhancing it so that the text continously loops.

My knowledge of javascript is very basic, so I've used this as a means of self-study.

My first attempt used jQuery's animate function... it was super smooth, but caused CPU to spike and any other script on the page to run very slowly.

So I've based my second attempt on `http://jqueryfordesigners.com/fun-with-overflows/` however, I've had complaint's that my new implementation it's not smooth enough...

http://darren.primarysite.net/marqueeTest/

I've spent a few weeks dipping in and out in my spare time, trying to refine it.. However, I'm stumped. Does anyone have any idea how I can make this smoother / faster etc?

I've put my code into pastebin - so its easily viewed.

http://pastebin.ca/2048170

and in the head...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#marQueeContainer').marQuee({gap: 5});  
$('#marQueeContainer1').marQuee(); 
});
</script>
```

and the following in the body...

```
<div id="marQueeContainer">An Example with a 5px text gap...</div>

<div id="marQueeContainer1">An example with defaults...</div>
```

Thanks,

Rob

Comment: return? i don't think so: http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/marquee

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-marquee/ - ok, so not a tag... but a collection of CSS properties.. the point is, a new marquee type thing is being touted.

Comment: IE6 not supporting google and Microsoft

Comment: why do you need a solution that works in IE6? It's at less than 2% usage in most countries now, and falling fast. If it's in your project specs that it needs to support IE6 then fair enough, but I hope they're paying you very well for it -- I would expect at least double rates if IE6 support was a requirement for anything I do these days.

Comment: 98% of our customers use IE. 32% use IE6. Our customers are not in any position to upgrade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use something like this:

```
var line = "     My line  ";

function marque() {
    $("#line").val(line);
    line=line.substring(1, line.length) + line.substring(0, 1);
    setTimeout(marque, 200);
}
marque();
```

Html

```
<input id="line" value="" />
```

Comment: WOW! I get it :) This works nicely, and is really tiny! Only thing is, it's just a bit too juddery. I've played with the timeout etc... and was unable to make it smoother. However, I'm really interested in how this works - so I'm going to read up on it :) Thanks!

Comment: @Rob If this answers helped you... you can accept it by checking the **V** mark. After you get more that 15 points, you can up-vote answers too. Happy coding and welcome to SO.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the increment size of scrollLeft and also lower the setInterval delay -- seems to be much smoother when I tested it in jsfiddle. Also try to cache values wherever possible.

Comment: Thanks :) I'm going to google and find out how to cache values